# Kotlin, sealed classes, children do not have to extend the parent class

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

There is no information about this in the official Kotlin docs, or I've missed it (here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html)

Although through testing I assume that my understanding is correct:

*you can omit specifying the supertype of children of a sealed class as the parent class' type if you do not need a child to access the sealed class' constructor parameters.*

In some way it is counterintuitive for me, but I can see possible usages.

**The purpose of the question is to know if I can sometimes write less code this way.**

I have a simple example here:

```
object SealedClassesTest2 {

sealed class Class1 {
    data class SubClass1(val value: String) : Class1()
}

sealed class Class2 {
    data class SubClass2(val value: String)
}

sealed class Class3(val parentVal: String) {
    data class SubClass3(val value: String) : Class3("Class3")
}

sealed class Class4(val parentVal: String) {
    data class SubClass4(val value: String)
}

@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val subClass1 = Class1.SubClass1("SubClass1")
    val subClass2 = Class2.SubClass2("SubClass2")
    val subClass3 = Class3.SubClass3("SubClass3")
    val subClass4 = Class4.SubClass4("SubClass4")
    println(subClass1.value)
    println(subClass2.value)
    println(subClass3.value)
    println(subClass3.parentVal)
    println(subClass4.value)
}

}
```

Output:

```
SubClass1
SubClass2
SubClass3
Class3
SubClass4
```

Here `Class1` and `Class2` have identical behaviour, even though I do not call the `Class2` constructor for the `SubClass2`. There are no errors in compilation or runtime.

For the `Class3` and `Class4` there are still no errors in compilation or runtime, but the difference is that I can address the `subClass3.parentVal` but do not have the access to `subClass4.parentVal` (because I haven't called the `Class4` constructor for the `SubClass4`)

I assume that when there are no parameters for the parent sealed class, I can skip calling its constructor for child classes, and the compiler does not see any difference.

Is that correct?

Comment: `SubClass4` is not a subclass of `Class4`. It's _nested_ inside `Class4`, but it's not a subclass. Same with `SubClass2` and `Class2`.

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html for more information

Comment: It has nothing really to do with sealed classes. It is only about if we subclass another class or not.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, I had such a suspicion. My initial problem was to do with Android and how I often had to create sealed classes/interfaces, from the purpose of using "when" statement. I've just tested and "when" indeed does not work with nested classes, only with subclasses.  I was confused for a moment because I'd never thought about it before.